# Accessing images in magento using soap api. cant access thumbnails. need image resizing

Tags: magento, image-processing, soap, image-resizing, magento-1.7

I am building a new third party application using soap api in magento which has ability to sell products on mobile.
But problem is that i didn't find any way to show reduced size images while fatching product list. 
I am using catalog_product_attribute_media.list to find image url but that url is of full size and big image. i am not able to find url of thumbnails and small_images using soap api.
This is because magento make them automatically.
I cant use big size images as this app is to use on mobile web.
Is there anyone who can tell me how to fix this small size image problem.
or tell me any method to use those thumbnails using soap api from magento.
If you know any on fly image size reduction method that can reduce image memory size then also plz tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this module, very good to deal with images and have resize methods, http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cloud-zoom-4634.html

Comment: Thanks for rply. But here I am concerned about third party application using soap so this extension cant solve my problem.

Comment: If you have something else then plz let me know... once again thankyou so much @Guerra.

Answer (score -2):

here is the [SOURCE](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeMedia/catalog_product_attribute_media.types.html),

> allows you to retrieve product image types including standard image,
>   small_image, thumbnail, etc.

**Request for SOAP API V1:**

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product_attribute_media.types', '4');
var_dump($result);

// If you don't need the session anymore
//$client->endSession($session);
```

**Response:**

```
array
  0 =>
    array
      'code' => string 'image' (length=5)
      'scope' => string 'store' (length=5)
  1 =>
    array
      'code' => string 'small_image' (length=11)
      'scope' => string 'store' (length=5)
  2 =>
    array
      'code' => string 'thumbnail' (length=9)
      'scope' => string 'store' (length=5)
```

Comment: the problem is that this api is only telling about types and the problem is that i want their urls.. What i can get is url of original size image but not of small_image and thumbnail. Any further solution ?? please let me know..

Comment: This is just a copy+paste from the Magento wiki and does not provide an answer to the (possibly confusingly worded) question, "How do I get resized image URLs through SOAP API?"